# Jmeter with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jmeter

I'm learning how to build `Jmeter` with Eclipse.

I followed some online steps and downloaded `Jmeter` binary and source files, unzipped them into the same directory, created a java project in eclipse and used `ant` build but when i build i got the following error

```
\workspace\apache-jmeter-2.11\build.xml:801: Class not found: javac1.8
```

I'm using `JRE8`, `JDK1.8` and `ant 1.9.4`.

Saw some similar post with answers saying that this is an issue with ant version `< 1.9` but i'm already using ant 1.9.4.

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that is a problem encountered with versions of Ant which are not compliant with Java 8, I suggest you check your Ant configuration. Go to your Eclipse settings and check it. Then, check your project settings, maybe you have project-specific settings which override your general Eclipse settings.

In the settings, you can choose which Ant install you want to use. By default, Eclipse is using it's own, which is probably not the last available. If you have installed Ant 1.9.4, you should select "External installation" or something, with the version of Ant you installed.

More infos here: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-ant-version.htm

Comment: thanks! solved that problem. now gotta deal with other issues.

Comment: @AlvinRL, You are facing the same challenge I faced when I started customizing JMeter and thought to utilize Eclipse to do the customization. In the section "2. Run JMeter using ANT target" of below link I have covered the ANT issue and other end to end configuration issues one may face.
[link](http://p3lang.com/2016/03/configure-jmeter-in-eclipse/)